# Is there a way to get the initial state?

Tags: react-native, state, react-navigation

I'm trying to reset the state of my click count. After 5 clicks users go to an other screen and in this other screen, there is a button that allows users to go back to the screen where my click count is but the state is still on 4 clicks.

i've tried to setstate my clicks to 0 with componentwillunmount, i tried to put a const initialstate with click 0 and call it in componentwillunmount

```
export default class Ecran1_Tactile extends React.Component {

//setting state

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      opacity: 0,
      click: 0,
    }  
  }
```

```
//My navigation after 4 clicks

  _displayScreen = () => {
    if(this.state.click === 4){
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Ecran2_Tactile')
    }
  }
```

```
//trying to reset state

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.setState({click: 0})
  }
```

I expect the state to go back to 0 as soon as users clicked 4 times but it remains 4

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of resetting clicks in `componentWillUnmount`, what if you added it to the logic wherever you're incrementing clicks in state? Have a check that says if clicks are 5 and the user clicks again, `setState` of clicks back to 0.

Answer (score 2):

My first debugging step would be to check if `componentWillUnmount()` is being called. You can use

```
componentWillUnmount(){

    this.setState({click: 0})
    console.log("componentWillUnmount called");

  }
```

Secondly, if your business logic expectations is "I expect the state to go back to 0 as soon as users clicked 4 times " why not just do the setState in the condition block?

```
//My navigation after 4 clicks

  _displayScreen = () => {
    if(this.state.click === 4){
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Ecran2_Tactile')
      this.setState({click: 0})
    }
  }
```